# how do I obtain a transfer function having an input and an output?

Tags: function, transfer, coefficients

my problem is the next one: 
I have an input signal and an output one. i need to find a transfer function in this form
H(s)=1/(as^2+bs+c). my goal is to have a,b and c.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signals and systems and belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let W be the tf, I the input and O the output.

in laplace IW=O, then you just need to do O/I and simplify it to get the W in the form you want,even if it would be better and more general to write it in the bode form.

Comment: how to do an O/I? sorry but I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: just do the ratio (division) with the two signals in laplace